# MySQL Transforming a SELECT command into an UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been tasked with updating our Database by **changing the value of the "value" column in the "ap_criteria" table from 0 to 1.**

I have to change those values for a specific group that I get when executing this:

```
SELECT id, name, surname
FROM ap_volunteer 
WHERE medical_certificate = 1 
AND (id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(id_volunteer) 
FROM ap_criteria 
WHERE id_type = 177 
AND value = '0'))
ORDER BY name ASC
```

I've had a few attempts but my limited experience with SQL is definitely showing. Here's my latest attempt :

```
UPDATE `ap_criteria`
INNER JOIN ap_volunteer ON ap_criteria.id_volunteer = ap_volunteer.id
WHERE medical_certificate = 1
AND (id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(id_volunteer) 
FROM ap_criteria
AND id_type = 177 AND value = 0))
SET ap_criteria.value = 1
```

Unfortunately that one ended in failure! I'd appreciate if someone could help me out and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
UPDATE ap_criteria c JOIN
       ap_volunteer v
       ON c.id_volunteer = v.id
    SET c.value = 1
WHERE medical_certificate = 1 AND
      id IN (SELECT c2.id_volunteer 
             FROM ap_criteria c2 
             WHERE c2.id_type = 177 AND
                   c2.value = 0
            );
```

You'll notice that I also added table aliases, qualified column names (where I could tell where they come from), and removed `DISTINCT` from the subquery where it is not needed.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you need to use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE ap_criteria c JOIN
       ap_volunteer v
       ON c.id_volunteer = v.id JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT c2.id_volunteer 
        FROM ap_criteria c2 
        WHERE c2.id_type = 177 AND
              c2.value = 0
       ) c2
       ON v.id = c2.id_volunteer
    SET c.value = 1
WHERE medical_certificate = 1 ;
```

Comment: I'll try that right away, thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: So I tried but no dice! (I changed the AND at line 7 to a WHERE) I get the following error: "You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: @Outjacked . . . I missed that.  I thought the other table was being updated.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, unfortunately I'm now getting this error : " Unknown column 'c2.id_volunteer' in 'on clause' "
The column id_volunteer is present in the ap_criteria table so I don't know what could be causing it :/